# How to copy an entity tree in database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a pretty standard relational data situation in which there is a root entity (and corresponding table) with children entities. These children have children entities and so on and so forth for about 6 levels. Each level has a many children to one parent relationship. I would like to write a procedure that effectively copies the root entity and all of its children entities (recursively copying the childrens' children), creating new entities for each along the way while storing each in its respective table.

I know this could be done with nested cursors, but I don't want to do it that way. I know that there is a more elegant solution out there I just need help creating it. I have a feeling that the solution lies in a combination of OUTPUT clauses and MERGE statements.

If you could, please tailor your answer to the novice SQL developer level. I will need an explanation or a link to an explanation for any structure you use that is outside of the basic SELECT INSERT UPDATE and DELETE.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What SQL version is this? (also, note that this is a significantly advanced task that you are attempting, it's not really suitable for a novice)

Comment: MERGE and OUTPUT are very good to solve this problem. You will probably need one MERGE statement plus one temp table per table to copy, executed in topological order top to bottom. Are you OK with manually typing all the statements once, or do you want a "reflection" based approach that construct the SQL at runtime?

Comment: I wonder what @RBarryYoung is thinking. Recursive common table expressions, anyone? Or is that not enough to solve it?

Comment: @Guttsy It depends a lot on the actual detail.  It's not clear from the description whether this is one self-referential table or whether there are other tables involved and how they are involved.  The OP will need to provide some of this information (in the form of table definitions and/or relational diagrams).

Comment: @usr: I am perfectly fine with manually typing each statement once, and I don't need a reflection based approach.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: This is SQL Server 2008 R2. Though I consider myself a novice, I am comfortable enough to work with complex solutions. To clear things up, each entity level is contained within its own table and the relationships are maintained by referential integrity. A relational diagram is not practical for me at present, however I think the situation is standard enough to be interpreted by you folks. Question, why did you remove specificity from the title?

Comment: @JameyOrr 1) You won't get any specific answers unless you give us more specific information.  As it currently stands we cannot tell which of several possible schemas you are dealing with.  2) I changed your title because titles are guidelined to not include languages or products in them (since that is supposed to be in the tags).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use common table expression. Check this:
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/04/24/sql-server-introduction-to-hierarchical-query-using-a-recursive-cte-a-primer/

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I read through the article and am still having difficulty piecing together how this can be applied to what I need to do. Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: I used CTE a lot, I have a table which is a correct tree (no loops)  and having columns:

    ID, parentID, otherInfo1, otherInfo2,...

In this structure it is easy to write such queries:

  GetAllCildrensOfXRecursive(X)
  GetAllAncestorsOfXRecursive(X)

Functions above runs till exit condition (there are no children for example). Let me know columns of your table, what exactly you need to query, and if your table having loops or not.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that you want to copy a subset of the data that is in a hierarchy of tables. By hierarchy I mean tables that are interrelated through foreign keys in the obvious sense of the word. For example, `Customers` would be a root table, `Orders` a child of it and `OrderDetails` another child (at the 3rd level).

First we copy the root table of the hierarchy:

```
MERGE RootTable as target
USING (
 SELECT *
 FROM RootTable
 WHERE SomeCondition
) AS src
ON 1=2 -- this is so that all rows that do not match will be added
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (AllColumns) VALUES (AllColumns)
OUTPUT src.ID as OldID, INSERTED.ID as NewID INTO #RootTableMapping
```

Now we have a 1 to 1 mapping of the copy source and copy target IDs of the root table in `#RootTableMapping`. Also, all root rows were copied.

We now need to copy all child tables. Here's the statement for one:

```
MERGE ChildTable as target
USING (
 SELECT *, #RootTableMapping.NewID AS NewParentID
 FROM ChildTable
 JOIN #RootTableMapping ON ChildTable.RootID = #RootTableMapping.OldID
 WHERE SomeCondition
) AS src
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (AllColumns, RootID) VALUES (AllColumns, NewParentID)
```

Here, we obtain for each child row the ID of the cloned root table row so that we can link up the hierarchy. For that we use `#RootTableMapping`. We copy all columns unmodified, except for the ID of the parent which we substitute with the `NewID` from the mapping.

You'd need one such `MERGE` statement for each child table. The concept also extends to hierarchies with more than 2 levels by adding additional joins. All levels except for the bottom level must record the mapping of copy-source IDs to copy-target IDs to allow the next layer below to obtain the new IDs.

Feel free to ask further questions in case I did not make everything clear enough. I know this is a rough sketch.